# getting index of '@' character in a string

Tags: jquery

assuming a function like this:

```
  var email = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var username = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('\\@'))
```

According to the jquery documentation, '\\' should escape the @ character, but it doesn't work. How can I specify the '@' character?

edit:
please see screenshot of my function. As you can see the @ character is being interpreted in a special way , because of Razor maybe?

[image]

Comment: You don't need to escape at all. Also there is no `jquery` in this question.

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You  don't need to escape the "@" in the `indexOf` function. This is standard javascript :

```js
var email = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var username = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@'));
  console.log(username );
```

Edit : for Razor engine ... Use `indexOf('@@')` to escape the @ symbol

Comment: Did you try using just a single "\" before the @ to escape the @ anyway .. works the same and might also prove helpful in your scenario.

Comment: Use @@ instead of just one @... So , .indexOf('@@')

Comment: great that works, thanks!  Perhaps you could upvote my question so at least I get it to 0 as it wasn't such a stupid question after all, although I could have used better search terms when i was originally looking for an answer.